# Var not defined (responsive-nav)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, var, responsive-nav

I’m using a responsive nav plug-in (responsive-nav.com) and have done for many projects. I love it and it works perfectly. I’ve started using CodeKit which checks javascript before it’s saved and it’s throwing up an error even though the plug-in works on the page. I’m more design/html/css so I just wanted to check i there’s another way to write/call the plug-in. Currently I use this:

```
$(function(){
   var navigation = responsiveNav(".site-nav__list", {
        insert: "before",
        customToggle: ".site-nav__toggle"
    });
});
```

I think this is correct from the documentation but I get the following 2 alerts/errors;

‘navigation’ is defined but never used. — column 9
‘responsiveNav’ is not defined. — column 22

I (think I) understand what this means but wondered if there was another way of writing the code? I don’t know how to adapt this so it doesn’t use a variable. I tried this instead:

```
$(function(){
    $(".site-nav__list").responsiveNav({
        customToggle: ".site-nav__toggle"
    });
})
```

Which returned no errors but then the plug-in stopped working. Looks pretty standard to be though?

Thanks, hope someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Why did you remove the `insert: "before"` when removing the unnecessary `navigation` variable? Removing a variable you don't use cannot make the plugin stop working. Removing one of the options to it could.

Comment: Ah sorry I meant to take it out - I actually have it commented out anyways. I just leave it in incase I need it, saves me looking through the documentation !

Comment: Well, again, removing the `navigation` variable can't, in and of itself, cause the plugin to stop working. So I suggest you delete the question, do some rigorous testing, and then if you need to repost, you can. You're quite right about the first warning and what to do about it. (The second is just that CodeKit doesn't know you have a global `responsiveNav` function.)

Comment: I think it _could be_ to do with the variable being set in the plug-in javascript file?

https://github.com/viljamis/responsive-nav.js/blob/master/responsive-nav.js

Comment: No, the plugin's code has no access to the `navigation` variable you've declared. That variable is entirely private to the code in your `ready` callback. That's how CodeKit knows it isn't used, and how I know removing it makes no difference. :-)

Comment: That variable is how they have it in the documentation, that's why it's odd. It makes me think it's something to do with how the plug-ins code is written!

Comment: Nope. The way JavaScript works, that's literally impossible. :-)